# Operation cannot be performed on an inactive dataset - Lazarus

Tags: delphi, runtime-error, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I tried to find someone with the same error, but I found out that there are many reasons for this error. Now let me explain my case. My application has 17 DBGrids, some with lookup fields. There's a specific one with three normal fields and one lookup. When I run the program it works normally, but when I register something in this table, close the program and run it again. It raises this exception:

> Project raised class exception 'EDatabaseError' with message:
>   Operation cannot be performed on an inactive dataset. No Adress:
>   5E0158.

The first time I open "MATERIAL" table to add a new register:

```
procedure TfrmMateria.bbtAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  prox: integer;
begin
  //Adiciona um novo registro na tabela
  dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Open;
  dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Last;
  prox := dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.FieldByName('MP_ID').AsInteger + 1;
  dmOrcamentos.zcOrcamento.StartTransaction;
  dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Append;
  dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.FieldByName('MP_ID').AsInteger := prox;
  dbgMaterial.SelectedIndex := 1;
  tratabotoes;
end;
```

This is the code I use to setup my PickList:

```
    procedure TfrmMateria.SetupGridPickList(const FieldName: string; const sql: string);
var
  slPickList: TStringList;
  Query: TZQuery;
  i: integer;
begin
  slPickList := TStringList.Create;
  Query := TZQuery.Create(self);
  try
    Query.Connection := dmOrcamentos.zcOrcamento;
    Query.SQL.Text := sql;
    Query.Open;
    //Preenche a String list
    while not Query.EOF do
    begin
      slPickList.Add(Query.Fields[0].AsString);
      Query.Next;
    end; //while

    //Coloca a lista na coluna correta
    for i := 0 to dbgMaterial.Columns.Count - 1 do
      if dbgMaterial.Columns[i].FieldName = FieldName then
      begin
        dbgMaterial.Columns[i].PickList := slPickList;
        Break;
      end;
  finally
    slPickList.Free;
    Query.Free;
  end;
end;
```

By the way, I call the SetupGridPickList on FormCreate:

```
procedure TfrmMateria.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetupGridPickList('UNIDADE_DESC', 'SELECT UNIDADE_DESC FROM UNIDADES_MEDIDA');
end;
```

The code I use to save my DBGrid:

```
    procedure TfrmMateria.bbtSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Salva alterações feitas na tabela
  if dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then
  begin
    dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Post;
    dmOrcamentos.zcOrcamento.Commit;
    dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Close;
    dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Open;
    tratabotoes;
  end
  else
  begin
    dmOrcamentos.zcOrcamento.StartTransaction;
    dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Post;
    dmOrcamentos.zcOrcamento.Commit;
    dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Close;
    dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Open;
    tratabotoes;
  end;
end;
```

When I close the form:

```
procedure TfrmMateria.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var canClose: boolean);
begin
  //Teste para saber se a tablea está "aberta" para
  if dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then
  begin
    //Pergunta se deseja salvar
    if MessageBox(frmMateria.Handle, 'Deseja salvar os dados pendentes?',
      'ONZE - AVISO', MB_YESNO + MB_SYSTEMMODAL + MB_ICONQUESTION) = idYes then
    begin
        dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Post;
        dmOrcamentos.zcOrcamento.Commit;
        dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Close;
        tratabotoes;
        CanClose := True;
    end {Fim pergunta se deseja salvar}
    else
    begin
      dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Cancel;
      dmOrcamentos.zcOrcamento.Rollback;
      tratabotoes;
      canClose := True;
    end;
  end{Fim do teste da planilha aberta}
  else
  begin
    canClose := True;
    dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Close;
  end;
end;
```

When I click th "HOME" button

```
procedure TfrmMateria.bbtHomeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Pergunta para voltar ao menu inicial
  if MessageBox(frmMateria.Handle, 'Deseja voltar ao menu inicial?',
    'ONZE - AVISO', MB_YESNO + MB_SYSTEMMODAL + MB_ICONQUESTION) = idYes then
  begin
    //Limpar da memória e fechar
    frmMateria.Release;
    frmMateria := nil;
    dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Close;
  end;

end;
```

The DataBase setup:

```
TABLES: |          MATERIAL          |  UNIDADES_MEDIDA  |
        |----------------------------|-------------------|
FIELDS: | MP_ID         (PRIMARY KEY)| UNIDADE_ID   (PK) |
        | MP_DESC                    | UNIDADE_DESC      |
        | MP_VALOR                   |-------------------|  
        | MP_UNIDADE_ID (FOREIGN KEY)|
        |----------------------------|
```

**On my program, the "MATERIAL" table has one more field, the LOOKUP one: 
"UNIDADE_DESC" with these properties:
KeyField:     MP_UNIDADE_ID
DataSet:      ztUnidade
Look Up Key:  UNIDADE_ID
Result Field: UNIDDE_DESC**

It does not show anything but the message and closes.
The thing is, if I delete this register data from database manually (I use IBExpert) and run the program again, it returns to work properly. 
Besides, all my tables without lookup fields are saving, the ones with lookup aren't. Hope you guys can help me, I have no idea why this is happening.

I use: ZEOS connection and FireBird 2.5 database.

Here's where the program stops: In ZAbstractRODataset
At this code section:

```
function TZAbstractRODataset.Lookup(const KeyFields: string;
  const KeyValues: Variant; const ResultFields: string): Variant;
var
  RowNo: Integer;
  FieldRefs: TObjectDynArray;
  FieldIndices: TIntegerDynArray;
  OnlyDataFields: Boolean;
  SearchRowBuffer: PZRowBuffer;
  ResultValues: TZVariantDynArray;
begin
  OnlyDataFields := False;
  Result := Null;
  RowNo := InternalLocate(KeyFields, KeyValues, []); <---- **HERE**
  FieldRefs := nil;
  FieldIndices := nil;
  if RowNo < 0 then
     Exit;
```

Where I put "HERE", when I use a breakpoint and place my mouse over "KeyFields", it shows "UNIDADE_ID" which is the key field for the lookup I use in my table and if I place it in "KeyValues" it shows "1".

OBS¹: I have another form, with almost the same code, the only different part is the table it is reffered to. This form has five Lookup Fields, one of the fields actually comes from this "MATERIAL" table. All of the fields are working normally and if I save a register on it and open again the program does not stop.

Comment: Without seeing any code, we can't help you. You say it works the first time. My guess is when you run it a second time your program does something different because hat "register" is present. Show some code and specify on which line your project gives the exception and we might be able to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31143909/edit) and include this information there instead of a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show some of your own code. Especially where you call Lookup or just trace back to your own code from this fragment. Also some logic as to why your program runs the first time and only gives the error a second time. You're probably doing a lookup for UNIDADE_ID on a closed dataset. If you locate that lookup on UNIDADE_ID you can break there and see if your dataset is active.

Comment: @Rik The thing is, I don't close my UNIDADE DataSet when I save my MATERIAL register.

Comment: Haven't got much time at the moment but... I noticed in bbtSaveClick that you do `dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Post;` in the else-part (when you're **not** in `[dsEdit, dsInsert]`-mode). That can't be right. You can't do a post when you're not in Edit/Insert mode. Remove that line. If it's still giving problems I look at the rest of the code tomorrow.

Comment: Where are you doing your initial `dmOrcamentos.ztMaterial.Open;`. I only see it in bbtAddClick. You should open your ztMaterial before you use your lookup/pick-fields. If you put it in FormCreate you can remove the Open in bbtAddClick (because it's already open). And remove everything between `else begin .... end;` in bbtSaveClick because when your ztMaterial.State is not in edit/insert mode you don't need to post/commit/close/open. You can just leave ztMaterial open without doing anything.

Comment: @Rik Well, I tried doing what you said, but the exception keeps showing. I had an idea, instead of creating a lookup field, I could use the SetupGridPickList to show the description directly in "MP_UNIDADE_ID" field. But the thing is, how can I select its description and save its ID? (I don't know exactly where can I put this question,  sorry if it's not here)

Comment: @Rik It's done, thank you for your effort! ^^

Comment: So it's all working now? Good. For questions which result in lots of messages back and forth, a forum might be a better place to post your question. Are you familiar with the Lazarus forum? http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/

Comment: Actually I know, but I was recommended to come here to ask. Next time I'll try this forum. Thanks again man @Rik